# How to quickly insert ~300GB/one billion record with relation into PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, bulkinsert

I have been working on this for months but still no solution, I hope I can get help from you ...

The task is, I need to insert/import real time data records from an online data provider into our database.

Real time data is provided in form of files. Each file contains up to 200,000 json records, one record one line. Every day several/tens of files are provided online, begins from year 2013.

I calculated the whole file store and got a total size of around 300GB. I estimated the whole number of records (I can get the file sizes via rest api but not line numbers of each file), it should be around one billion records or a little bit more.

Before I can import/insert one record into our database, I need to find out two parameters (station, parameter) from the record and make relationship.

So the workflow is something like:

1. Find parameter in our database, if the parameter exists in our db, just return parameter.id; otherwise the parameter should be inserted into parameter table as a new entry and a new parameter.id will be created and returned;
2. Find station in our database, similarly, if that station exists already, just take its id, otherwise a new station will be created and a new station.id will be created;
3. Then I can insert this json record into our main data table with its identified parameter.id and station.id to make relationship.

Basically it is a simple database structure with three main tables (data, parameter, station). They are conneted by parameter.id and station.id with primary key/foreign key relationship.

But the querying is very time consuming and I cannot find a way to properly insert this amound of data into the database in a foreseeable time.

I did two trials:

1. Just use normal SQL queries with bulk insert.
   The workflow is described above.
   For each record a) get parameter.id b) get station.id c) insert this record
   Even with bulk insert, I could only insert one million records in a week. The records are not that short and contain about 20 fields.
2. After that, I tried following:
   I don't check parameter and station in advance, but just use COPY command to copy the records into a intermediate table with no relation. For this I calculated, all the one billion records can be imported in around ten days.
   But after the COPY, I need to manully find out all dictinct stations (there are only a few parameters so I can ignore the parameter part) with SQL query `select distinct` or `group by`, and create these stations in the station table, and then `UPDATE` the whole records with their corresponding station.id, but this `UPDATE` operation takes very very long.

Here is an example:
I spent one and a half days to import 33,000,000 records into the intermediate table.
I queried with select `longitude, latitude from records group by longitude, latitude` and got 4,500 stations
I inserted these 4,500 stations into the station table
And for each station I do

```
update record set stationid = station.id where longitude=station.longitude and latitude=station.latitude
```

The job is still running but I estimate it will take two days
And this is only for 30,000,000 records, I have one billion.

So my question is, how can I insert this amount of data into the database quickly?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

2020-08-20 10:01
Thank you all very much for the comments!

@Brits:
Yes and no, all the "COPY"s took over 24 hours. One "COPY" command for one json file. For each file I need doing following:

1. Download the file
2. Flat the Json file (no relation check of station, but with parameter check, it is very easy and quick, parameter is like constant in the project) to a CSV like text file for "COPY" command
3. Execute the "COPY" command via Python
   1, 2 and 3 all together will take if I am in the company network around one minute for a Json file containing ~ 200,000 records, and around 20 minutes if I work from home.
   So just ignore the "one and a half day" statement. My estimation is, if I work in the company network, I will be able to import all 300GB/One billion records into my intermediate table without relation check in ten days.

I think my problem now is not to move the json content into a flat database table, but to build the relationship between data - station.
After I have my json content in the flat table, I need to find out all stations and update all records with:

1. select longitude, latitude, count(*) from records group by longitude, latitude
2. insert these longitude latitude combination into station table
3. for each entry in station table, do
   update records set stationid = station.id where longitude=station.longitude and latitude=station.latitude

This 3. above takes very long (also 1. takes several minutes only for 34million records, I have no idea how long 1. will take for one billion records)

@Mike Organek @Laurenz Albe Thanks a lot. Even your comments are now for me difficult to understand. I will study them and give a feedback.

---

The total file count is 100,000+
I am thinking about to parse all the files and get individual stations firstly, and then with station.id and parameter.id in advance do the "COPY"s. I will give a feedback.

---

2020-09-04 09:14

I finally got what I want, even I am not sure whether it is correct.

What I have done since my question:

1. Parse all the json files and extract unique stations by coordinate and save them into the station table
2. Parse all the json files again and save all the fields into the record table, with parameter id from constants and station id from 1), with COPY command

I did 1) and 2) in a pipeline, they were done parallelly. And 1) took longer than 2), so I always needed to let 2) wait.

And after 10 days, I have my data in the postgres, with ca. 15000 stations, and 0.65 billion records in total, each records has the corresponding station id.

@steven-matison Thank you very much and could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: I am putting this in a comment because it is not a solution.  Would your data take to partitioning on timestamps well?  If so, have you considered using the TimescaleDB extension?   Have you tried a hybrid approach of using `copy` to bring in an individual file of up to 200,000 records and then use the json functions with queries to perform the maintenance of the `station` and `parameter` tables?  If you can partition and handling individual files works, then you might be able to parallelize the loading across years so long as you have the CPUs and IOPS necessary to handle simultaneous loads.

Comment: When you say "I spent one and a half days to import 33,000,000 records" do you mean that the `COPY` took over 24 hours? (I would expect this to be a lot quicker but it depends upon what you are importing into). Perhaps you could post the SQL statements you ran (from `CREATE TABLE record`) and indicate approximately how long each took (so we can see exactly where the issues are, confirm `COPY` vs `\COPY`, see how you are extracting longitude, latitude from the JSON, assess the impact of indexes/constraints etc).

Comment: Your second approach is promising. With proper hardware and tuning, `COPY` can be much faster. Then run single `DELETE` statements that join the loaded table with the existing ones and remove rows as necessary. If most rows are removed, it will be faster to generate a new table and insert the surviving rows there. Tune these statements. It may save the day to split the billion rows in parts and deal with each part concurrently.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "make relationship"? When you go beyond a certain point performing joins will become costly in a database. So you might want to de-normalize and make the table self-sustained, ie. no dependency on other tables. It may be the process of looking up station-id, insert if not found, that takes time, because it's done for each row. That can be done in three phases, import, select those with a known station name, update id, select with unknown and insert + update.

Comment: Seven pages of text and not one mention of spec for Postgres and/or the system for gathering data...   This is a simple use case for distributed processing, clustering, and NOT using traditional "Postgres" for querying parameters, or processing, and storing inbound and outbound data.  -1